# Angular form not sending data

Tags: angular, data-binding

I'm having issues with a form in Angular not sending data and I'm sure it's a binding issue but I don't know how to resolve it.

I'm retrieving a set of data from a database and populating a list of users and connecting to another control that renders a form to allow for updating the user:

#### User Listing

```
<div class="wrapper cf">

<div class="user-list">

<ul class="user-display-data users">
<li *ngFor="let user of users" class="cf"
[class.selected]="user === selectedUser"
(click)="onSelect(user); showDetails=1;">
<div class="user-badge-link" ><span class="display-data user-badge">{{user.first_name}} {{user.last_name}}</span>
<span class="user-display-data user-display-edit">Edit</span></div>
</li>
</ul>

</div>

<div class="user-details" *ngIf="showDetails === 1" >
<app-user-detail [user]="selectedUser"></app-user-detail>
</div>

</div>
```

#### Update Form

```
   <div class="details-wrapper">
    <div>
    <h2 class="sub-head-h2">{{user.first_name}} {{user.last_name}} Account Details</h2>
    <div class="user-detail-data">
    <div class="input-row">
    <label>First Name:</label>
    <input ng-model="first_name" value="{{user.first_name}}" />
    </div>
    <div class="input-row-odd">
    <label>Last Name:</label>
    <input ng-model="last_name" value="{{user.last_name}}" />
    </div>
    <div class="input-row">
    <label>Email:</label>
    <input ng-model="email" value="{{user.email}}" />
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" ng-model="id" value="{{user.id}}" />
    <button class="small-button" (click)="save()">Update User</button>
    <button class="small-button" (click)="delete()">Delete User</button>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

I have a function set up in my service to update the user on click:

#### Update User

```
updateUser (user: User): Observable<any> {

var userUpdatedUrl = 'http://dbs:8888/user-update/' + user.id + '/' + user.first_name + '/' + user.last_name + '/' + user.email + '/' + user.password;

console.log(userUpdatedUrl);

return this.http.get(userUpdatedUrl).pipe(tap(_ => this.log(`updated user id=${user.id}`)), catchError(this.handleError<any>('updateUser'))
);
}
```

The updateUser function fires when the button is clicked (the console logs the URL) but the values that populate the update form initially are the values sent to the endpoint, not the updated field values in the update form itself so I'm sure my fields aren't bound to the model properly (or at all maybe). Any ideas what might be going wrong?

Comment: are you using angular or angularjs?

Comment: Angular as far as I know, I installed it via the Angular CLI. Sorry I'm new to this angular thing.

Comment: in which case, the reason your data binding doesnt work is because youre using angularjs data binding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using angular 2 or above, i believe you might need to take look on basic form validations and data bindings as in your code I can see the data binding is not correct.
You might find the following useful:
https://angular.io/guide/form-validation

Comment: Thanks, this was it. I knew my bindings were off somehow and using this example I was able to resolve them.